# Conditional sort order in SQL Server windowed function clauses

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

So, this is not your average 'conditional sort by' question... I have a rather tricky problem here.  :-)  I want to allow my stored procedure to offer a conditional sort order for the results.  Normally this can be done in the following manner:

```
SELECT *
INTO #ResultsBeforeSubset
FROM
    MyTable
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN @SortAscending=1 THEN 'SortColumn' END ASC,
    CASE WHEN @SortAscending=0 THEN 'SortColumn' END DESC
```

I'd like to do a `CASE` statement around the actual `ASC`/`DESC`, but that doesn't work.  The reason the above method works is because, when `@SortAscending` isn't equal to the given value, SQL server translates the `CASE` statement into the constant `NULL`.  So, if `@SortAscending` is 0, you effectively have:

```
ORDER BY
    NULL ASC,
    SortColumn DESC
```

The first sort expression, then, just does nothing.  This works because in a regular `SELECT` statement you can use constant in an `ORDER BY` clause.

Trouble is, the time that I'm sorting in my stored proc is during a `SELECT` statement which contains a windowed function `ROW_NUMBER()`.  I therefore want to put the `CASE` statement inside its `OVER` clause, like so:

```
SELECT *
INTO #ResultsBeforeSubset
FROM (
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            ORDER BY
                CASE WHEN @SortAscending=1 THEN rowValues.[SortColumn] END ASC,
                CASE WHEN @SortAscending=0 THEN rowValues.[SortColumn] END DESC
        ) AS RowNumber,
        *
    FROM (
        -- UNIONed SELECTs returning rows go here...
    ) rowValues
) rowValuesWithRowNum
```

Unfortunately, this causes the following error when you run the stored procedure:

```
Windowed functions do not support constants as ORDER BY clause expressions.
```

Because this is the clause of a windowed function, the conversion of the `CASE` statement to the constant `NULL` is invalid.

Can anyone think of a way that I can conditionally vary the sort order of `UNION`ed `SELECT`s, and assign row numbers to each row resulting from these sorted results?  I know I could resort to constructing the entire query as a string and execute that as fully dynamic SQL, but I'd rather avoid that if possible.

---

**UPDATE:** Looks like the problem wasn't caused by the `CASE` statement *per se*, but by the fact that I was using only constant values in the `CASE` statement's conditional clause.  I've started up a new question on this curious behaviour [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7204979/curious-inconsistent-behaviour-from-sql-server-in-windowed-function-clauses).

Comment: +1 for the well written question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could assign row numbers in two directions, and pick one in an outer `order by`:

```
select  *
from    (
        select  row_number() over (order by SortColumn) rn1
        ,       row_number() over (order by SortColumn) rn2
        ,       *
        from    @t
        ) as SubQueryAlias
order by
        case when @asc=1 then rn1 end
,       case when @asc=0 then rn2 end desc
```

Working example at [SE Data](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/110512/).

Comment: I already addressed this in the question; this would create a constant inside the windowed function's clause, causing the error I'm getting now.

Comment: @Jez: Just checked my original answer, and that too [works fine](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/110515/).  The problem might be that you're quoting the column name; `'SortColumn'` is indeed a constant.

Comment: Ah! Your [original answer](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/110515/) that you linked above made me wonder why mine wasn't working, and it turns out the problem was not with the `CASE` statement being there, but the fact that I had been using constants in the `CASE` statement's conditional clause! [This query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/110520/) (I suggest you link it in your answer) shows the issue; uncomment the 2 `case` statements with int constants in them and the query fails. However when I don't use such constants in the `case` statement it works fine! Thx.

Comment: Actually, this behaviour is curious enough it may warrant further investigation. Logically, if `ORDER BY CASE WHEN @MyVar=1 THEN SortColumn END ASC` works, surely `ORDER BY CASE WHEN 1=1 THEN SortColumn END ASC` should too, assuming `@MyVar` is an int that may evaluate to 1? Yet, the latter causes an error and the former doesn't. And, because the `CASE` statement may evaluate to `NULL` if its conditional is false, this should work too, but also gives the error: `ORDER BY NULL ASC`.

Answer (score 3):

You could use constants if you wrap them in a SELECT, such as:

```
OVER( ORDER BY (SELECT NULL) )
```

So in your case you should be able to do:

```
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        ORDER BY
            (SELECT CASE WHEN @SortAscending=1 THEN rowValues.[SortColumn] END) ASC,
            (SELECT CASE WHEN @SortAscending=0 THEN rowValues.[SortColumn] END) DESC
    ) AS RowNumber,
```

Comment: An elegant solution that gets the job done efficiently for me. I haven't had the time to check, but I suspect that in SQL Server the execution plans will be much more efficient for this solution than the others, because the Database Engine doesn't necessarily have to calculate the windowing function twice, once for each direction, as it does for some of the others.

Comment: Nice. Would have never thought to put a select there, and I can't believe that worked.

Answer (score 1):

You could

- add both an Ascending and Descending column to your intermediate results
- sort on one of those at the end.

#### SQL Statement

```
SELECT  *
INTO    #ResultsBeforeSubset
FROM    (
          SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY rowValues.[SortColumn] ASC) AS AscSortColumn
                  , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY rowValues.[SortColumn] DESC) AS DescSortColumn
                  , *
          FROM    (-- UNIONed SELECTs returning rows go here...
                  ) rowValues
        ) rowValuesWithRowNum
ORDER BY
        CASE  WHEN @SortAscending = 1 
              THEN rowValues.[AscSortColumn] 
              ELSE rowValues.[DescSortColumn] 
        END
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to use these row numbers as part of some other conditional logic, maybe something like this would work:

```
CASE WHEN @SortAscending=1 THEN COUNT(*) OVER() + 1 ELSE 0 END +
(CASE WHEN @SortAscending=1 THEN -1 ELSE 1 END *
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SortColumn DESC)) as RowNumber
```

This can even be extended so that if you're using `PARTITION` clauses, it continues to work so long as both `OVER()` expressions use the same `PARTITION` clauses.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @sign int = -1;
IF @SortAscending = 0 SET @sign = -1;

SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RowNumber) AS RN,
    *
INTO #ResultsBeforeSubset
FROM (
    SELECT
        @sign * ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY rowValues.[SortColumn]) AS RowNumber,
        *
    FROM MyTable
) rowValuesWithRowNum
ORDER BY RN

--DECLARE @sign int = 1;
--IF @SortAscending = 0 SET @sign = -1;
--
--SELECT *
--INTO #ResultsBeforeSubset
--FROM (
--    SELECT
--        @sign * ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY rowValues.[SortColumn] AS RowNumber,
--        *
--    FROM MyTable
--) rowValuesWithRowNum
--ORDER BY RowNumber;
```

Comment: Again, this *nearly* does what I want, but the resulting `RowNumbers` are going to be negatives (eg. -10 .. -1) instead of positives (eg. 1 .. 10), if `@SortAscending` is `0`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a windowing function in the `order by`, not just in the select.  The windowing functions row_number, rank, dense_rank, all return a number (bigint) which you can multiply by a negative value to get the reverse...

```
SELECT *
INTO #ResultsBeforeSubset
FROM MyTable
ORDER BY
  (rank() over (order by SortColumn)) * case when @asc=1 then 1 else -1 end
```