# Curious inconsistent behaviour from SQL Server in windowed function clauses?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Whilst asking [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203110/conditional-sort-order-in-sql-server-windowed-function-clauses), I discovered that SQL Server (happens both in 2005 and 2008) seems to have strange inconsistent behaviour when dealing with `CASE` statements in the clauses of windowed functions.  The following code gives an error:

```
declare @t table (SortColumn int)
insert @t values (1), (2), (3)
declare @asc bit
set @asc = 0

select  row_number() over (order by
            case when 1=1 then SortColumn end asc,
            case when 1=0 then SortColumn end desc) RowNumber
,       *
from    @t
```

The error is **Windowed functions do not support constants as ORDER BY clause expressions.**  I presume this is because the `case` statement might evaluate to `NULL`, which is a constant.  As might also be expected, this code gives the same error:

```
declare @t table (SortColumn int)
insert @t values (1), (2), (3)
declare @asc bit
set @asc = 0

select  row_number() over (order by
            NULL asc,
            NULL desc) RowNumber
,       *
from    @t
```

... presumably for the same reason.  However, this code does not give an error:

```
declare @t table (SortColumn int)
insert @t values (1), (2), (3)
declare @asc bit
set @asc = 0

select  row_number() over (order by
            case when @asc=1 then SortColumn end asc,
            case when @asc=0 then SortColumn end desc) RowNumber
,       *
from    @t
```

The only difference here from the first codeblock is that I have moved one of the `case` statements' conditional operands into a variable, `@asc`.  This now works fine.  Why, though?  The `case` statements may still evaluate to `NULL`, which is a constant, so it shouldn't work... but it does.  Is this consistent somehow, or is it special case behaviour put in by Microsoft?

All this behvaiour can be checked by playing around with [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/110520/).

---

**Update:** This restriction doesn't just apply to `OVER` clauses (though they do give a different error) - it applies to all `ORDER BY` clauses since SQL Server 2005.  [Here's a query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/110634/) that also shows the restriction with a regular `SELECT`'s `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: Isn't `1=1` also a constant? It evaluates always to `TRUE`.

Comment: @Crack Yes, but it's a constant within a `case` statement so I don't see why that makes a difference?  That would seem to be saying, "If the statement definitely evaluates (or not) to NULL, it's not allowed.  If it *might* evaluate to NULL, it's allowed."  That doesn't make sense... why would the latter be allowed?  How is it more valid a syntax?

Comment: You can order by a constant. Use `ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)` or `ORDER BY @@SPID`

Comment: Did you try to actually *order by* the expressions that cause errors with windowed functions? They produce errors in the proper ORDER BY too: 'A constant expression was encountered in the ORDER BY list, position *n*'. So this works and breaks consistently in ORDER BY, regardless of its being used in windowed functions.

Comment: @Andriy - [This depends on compatibility mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx). A very similar discussion is here http://dbaspot.com/sqlserver-programming/466667-what-parts-sql-query-can-parameterized-what-parts-cant.html

Comment: @Martin: I didn't know that, thanks for enlightening. However, the MSDN article says nothing about whether the compatibility mode influences the behaviour of ORDER BY depending upon whether it is used at the end of a query or as part of the OVER clause. I would assume it changes both.

Comment: @Andriy - The `OVER` clause was only introduced in 2005 (SQL Server (90) compatibility mode) and the restriction against constants came in at the same time. I'm not sure whether the one led to the other.

Comment: @Martin Thanks for sharing.  I'm a bit confused by this in the MSDN article, though: *A sort column can include an expression, but when the database is in SQL Server (90) compatibility mode, the expression cannot resolve to a constant.*  I'm curious as to what they mean by 'resolve' here.  A `CASE` statement that may resolve to NULL *may* resolve to a constant.  Does MS enforce a rule where it's allowed, but only if it *may* resolve to a constant?  Does anyone know what MS's purpose was for imposting this restriction?

Comment: @Jez - I'm confused as well. It would seem to be whether or not it can resolve to a constant at compile time. However if you look at the execution plan for `SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY @@SPID) FROM master..spt_values` then you will see that the `@@spid` function never actually gets called so in this case the optimiser obviously recognises it is a constant but allows it. Not sure of the reason for the restriction either.

Comment: And `DECLARE @foo INT; SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY @foo) FROM master..spt_values` works too.

Comment: Thinking about it the criteria seems to be that if it gets resolved to a known constant value at compile time it is disallowed but it does allow constructs that will be constant at runtime but for which it cannot actually calculate the constant value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Books online indicates that "A sort column can include an expression, but when the database is in SQL Server (90) compatibility mode, the expression cannot resolve to a constant." however it does not define "constant".

From thinking about it and some experimentation it seems clear that this means an expression for which a literal constant value can successfully be calculated at compile time.

```
/*Works - Constant at run time but SQL Server doesn't do variable sniffing*/
DECLARE @Foo int
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY @Foo) 
FROM master..spt_values 

/*Works - Constant folding not done for divide by zero*/
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY $/0) 
FROM master..spt_values 

/*Fails - Windowed functions do not support 
   constants as ORDER BY clause expressions.*/
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY $/1) 
FROM master..spt_values
```

Comment: This looks like an accurate description of the restriction.  *Why* the restriction is in place is another matter, though...

Answer (score 0):

**The evaluations in your first example will never change.**

You are comparing a constant to a constant which will constantly result in a constant.

`1=1` will always be `TRUE`.
`1=0` will always be `FALSE`.

Comment: The same question applies here as the one I asked @Crack before; are you saying that the rule is, "If the statement definitely evaluates (or not) to NULL, it's not allowed. If it *might* evaluate to NULL, it's allowed." That doesn't make sense... why would the latter be allowed? How is it more valid a syntax?

Comment: The rule is "if  there is a constant evaluation it can't be in an `OVER` clause", I suspect.

Comment: Seems like a weird rule to me.  If SQL Server can deal with non-constant evaluations, shouldn't it be - if anything - easier to deal with constant ones?

Comment: @Jez - not when  the `ORDER BY` is essential to the window function working.  If you could saw `OVER(ORDER BY 'blah')` then that would be pointless.  SQL Server is very good about not letting you do things that will give unexpected results, unlike some other RDBMS

Comment: @JNK - there are occasions when you just need a sequence and don't care about ordering and using a constant allows you to avoid an unnecessary sort. [One example here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7163275/how-to-add-an-identity-column-to-an-existing-database-table-which-has-large-numbe/7164166#7164166)

Comment: @JNK But my point is that even the `CASE` statements that work can ultimately resolve to a constant anyway.  `case when @asc=1 then SortColumn end asc` resolves to `null asc` when `@asc` is not 1.

Comment: @Jez - you aren't EVALUATING a constant though

Comment: @JNK So?  I don't see how that should matter; only what it CAN evaluate to.

Comment: @Jez - then take it up with Microsoft, I didn't write it :)