# T-SQL Dollar Sign In Expressions

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7213596/3345644), there is a trick which allows to use the `ROW_NUMBER()` windowed function with a 'constant' in the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY $/0) 
FROM master..spt_values
```

After some search in Google, I can't find **what dollar sign means in this context?**

I've tried to execute a simple query:

```
SELECT $;
```

And it returns `0`.

Could somebody explain this?

Comment: I would expect $/0 to throw exception devide by 0 but it works. I wouldn't use this hack.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri, I was surprised it works too and that's exactly because I've started to dig into this trick. And I don't like it by the same reason, but I don't know another alternative for now.

Comment: The alternative is standart dummy select `SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))`

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri, Oh, you're right! :) Thank you! I was so close to this by trying something like `SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SELECT (NULL))` but, of course, I get an error :) Will use your suggestion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's just a [`money` constant](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179899.aspx) (what T-SQL calls literals).

You presumably would have been less surprised if you saw the expression `$2.50`, which would just be another constant.

Some other examples: `select £,¢,¤,¥,€` all return 0s also.

---

It can be tricky to determine what type of data you're looking at in T-SQL. One trick, if you *suspect* you know what type it is is to pick an [incompatible type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) and attempt the conversion:

```
select CONVERT(date,$)
```

Result:

```
Msg 529, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Explicit conversion from data type money to date is not allowed.
```

Comment: `SELECT SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY($, 'BaseType')` would be better.

Comment: I had no idea. Here's the best full list I have so far for anyone that needs it, using http://www.xe.com/symbols.php and SSMS. select $,£,¢,¤,¥,€,₡,₱,﷼,₩,₮,₨,₫,฿,៛,₪,₭,₦;

Comment: and the list keeps growing for me, http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Sc/list.htm . 
select $,£,¢,¤,¥,€,₡,₱,﷼,₩,₮,₨,₫,฿,៛,₪,₭,₦,৲,৳,﹩,₠,₢,₣,₤,₥,₧,₪,₯,₰,＄,￠,￡,￥,￦;

Comment: The dollar sign is also used in column references to graph database edge tables.  See ($edge_id) in  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/graphs/sql-graph-architecture?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @Damien for pointing to the right direction.

I'd just like to add to his answer results of a query that gives an exact description what are constants with the `$` sign:

```
  SELECT
    $ AS Value,
    SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY ( $ , 'BaseType' ) AS BaseType,
    SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY ( $ , 'Precision' ) AS Precision,
    SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY ( $ , 'Scale' ) AS Scale,
    SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY ( $ , 'TotalBytes' ) AS TotalBytes,
    SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY ( $ , 'MaxLength' ) AS MaxLength
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    $2.50,
    SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY ( $2.50 , 'BaseType' ),
    SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY ( $2.50 , 'Precision' ),
    SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY ( $2.50 , 'Scale' ),
    SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY ( $2.50 , 'TotalBytes' ),
    SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY ( $2.50 , 'MaxLength' )
```

Results:

```
Value   BaseType    Precision   Scale   TotalBytes  MaxLength  
0.00    money       19          4       10          8  
2.50    money       19          4       10          8
```